# Random Alert Box Content

Tags: javascript, arrays

For a project I'm working on, I'm trying to make it so that when a button is pressed, an alert box pops up with a message. The message is randomly selected from an array.

I tried this already:

```
const rockTalk = [
  'George is happy. Probably.',
  'George is a bit parched, and would be most pleased if you provided him with a drink',
  'George is going to sleep now.',
]

var randomItem = rockTalk[Math.floor(Math.random() * rockTalk.length)]
document.body.innerHTML = randomItem
var george = document.getElementById('georgeSprite')

function georgeSpeaks() {
  alert('' + randomItem)
}

george.onclick = georgeSpeaks()
```

Comment: Please correct the formatting, it's very difficult to read.

Comment: Think about where the element selection logic lives. It's only being set once.

Comment: `george.onclick = georgeSpeaks()` makes no sense. `onclick` is intended to be either `null` or a function, but `georgeSpeaks()` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost working. I have made a few changes so that it works.

1. The last comma in your `rockTalk` array adds 1 to the length of the array. In turn, this means that the random generator sometimes returns `undefined`.
2. `var randomItem = rockTalk[Math.floor(Math.random() * rockTalk.length)]` works fine, but you have placed it outside of the `georgeSpeaks` function. This means that  it only runs once and so always produces the same message. I have placed it inside the function which corrects this.
3. `document.body.innerHTML = randomItem` doesn't do anything so I have removed it.
4. I have re-worked your code into a more conventional style.
5. Semi-colons are not required in JavaScript - they indicate the end of a statement - but they make code more readable.
6. This is your main mistake. Event handlers such as `onclick` require a function *reference*, which is the function name. Adding brackets *executes* the function, and in your case the returned value (`undefined`) is assigned to the event handler.

Your working code:

```js
const rockTalk = [
  'George is happy. Probably.',
  'George is a bit parched, and would be most pleased if you provided him with a drink',
  'George is going to sleep now.'
];

function georgeSpeaks() {
   alert(rockTalk[Math.floor(Math.random() * rockTalk.length)]);
}

var george = document.getElementById('georgeSprite');
george.onclick = georgeSpeaks;
```

```html
<button id='georgeSprite'>A rock</button>
```